# Loading different HTML code into one single page on different link clicks

Tags: html, asp.net

So, my boss has this crazy idea - the whole website working on one single page. So far - still ok, but here's the thing:
- the different pages have different `div`s with content (like usual), and when some div is clicked (or link in it) some of the divs expand/collapse, working in the way of revealing different content. That's fine, but...

- he doesn't want to use JavaScript or anything for dynamic view of the website ('cuz I am leaving in 2 weeks and him and the other employee are not capable of JS, thus cannot improve/maintain if needed)
- his idea is to have the HTML code, for all the pages variations of the website, stored in the database, and upon clicking some link - reloading the page with the certain HTML. So not different `.html` files for every page, but only one for all of them.

The problem is that it works for the first page that I load, initially, but then when I call another page, it gets twisted, since I call the function, that retrieves the HTML, but the other call of the previously loaded page is still there, so it calls again. Here's sample, so you understand:

```
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
        public string getPage(string name)
    {
        string page = "null";
        switch (name)
        {
            case "media":
                page = getMediaPage(); <!-- just function from the code-behind that retrieves the html code from the DB and passes it to the page -->
                break;
            case "home":
                page = getHomePage(); <!-- just function from the code-behind that retrieves the html code from the DB and passes it to the page -->
                break;                    
        }
        return page;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="addEvents();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="presentation">
            SomeCompany ApS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Street3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CITY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;INFO@Comapny.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TLF: 999999
        </div>

        <%=getPage("home") %>

    </div>
    </form>
```

So that's how the initial page will be and then just in the `parent` div I will call the HTML for the  other pages. One example of HTML, stored in the DB:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
            <b>HOME</b>
            <br />
            PRODUCTS
            <br />
            <a href="<%=getPage("media")%>">SUPPORT</a>
            <br />
            CONTACT
            <br />
            ABOUT
            <br />
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
        </div>
```

So I call this chunk of code slam it in the page. The twist happens as I have `<a href="<%=getPage("media")%>">` clicked, so it loads the page normally, but there is `<%=getPage("home") %>` standing statically in the page, ALL THE TIME, as I need to start from somewhere, and it attempts to load the previous page again, and... server error.

I know it's kinda stupid idea, but I can't argue with him anymore.

So my question is - is there way of handling all this with some kind of `OnClick(Event e)` or some other way out, with calling different functions (as I already started). 
Or I should just tell the boss that it's not gonna work this way...

Comment: Tell your boss to hire someone who knows JS.

Comment: What he wants is a "Single Page Application", or SPA. Visual Studio 2012 has a template that can give you an idea of a good way to do this. I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish the task that aren't terrible, but... storing static html in a database is bad.. one of the worst ways to break the separation of concerns principle.

Comment: @JasonP - yeah, but I am working with VS2010, and I don't really want to deal with MVC and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, this isn't a great idea, but you could get it to work by using some Web Controls.

Where you have `<%=getPage("home") %>` in your page, change this to:

```
<asp:literal id="ltlContent" runat="server" />
```

On `Page_Load` call:

```
ltlContent.Text = getPage("home");
```

Any links on your page which should load other content, change these to `LinkButton` controls, and their click events could have:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="linkMedia" runat="server" onclick="LoadContent" CommandArgument="media" />

public void LoadContent(object sender, EventArgs e){
    ltlContent.Text = getPage(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

Comment: How would I pass the `"home"` parameter in here: `<asp:LinkButton OnClick="assignPage("home")" Text="FORSIDEN" runat="server" />` cuz I get error about incorrect syntax.

Comment: ah, so you mean that I have to have a different callback function to put in the controls, for each page... I see.

Comment: @Syspect You could pass a `CommandArgument` and just use the one method instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx . I'm just showing POC

Comment: Ok, I've got this `<asp:LinkButton ID="linkHome" Text="HOME" OnClick="loadHome()" runat="server" />` and get the error `Method name expected`, whereas I have the method in my code-behind, with the same name... And I am wondering why the compiler gives me this error.

Comment: @Syspect Edited my answer. Note `Onclick` value doesn't contain `()`

Comment: I tried editing my comment by saying that I tried it also without `()` but then I was getting another error: ` No overload for 'loadForsiden' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'`, but never mind, because I made it work with the `CommandArgument`. Thanks for all the suggestions and help!

Answer (score 0):

you could try the parameters on the get url.
add them on your link "?page=media"
and then you parse the url when you arrive $_GET["page"]

Comment: I don't wanna use query strings.